# Qt5 QML error QtQuick QtGraphicalEffects is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

After successful compilation of project, I have get an executable file.

When I type `./program` in result I see:

```
QML Error: qrc:///qml/main.qml:25:1:module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed
qrc:///qml/main.qml:24:1:module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

I'm using QtQuick 2.0, Qt5 and Ubuntu, QtQuick and QtGraphicalEffects are in `~/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/qml/` I have install fresh Qt SDK from site project.

I have tried run this application also on Windows 7 but with the same result.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

This is because Windows or whatever OS you use doesn't know the location of Qt install directory and it can't find the QML plugins sub-dir when you run app outside QtCreator.

You have to take the following directories from your SDK install and copy them beside your executable (and DLL) :

```
<SDK install path>/<Qt version>/<compiler name>/qml/QtQuick.2
<SDK install path>/<Qt version>/<compiler name>/qml/QtGraphicalEffects
```

And it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure to have the package installed

I see you mentioned about Ubuntu, if using 14.04 , you can install it by typing this command line :

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5qml-graphicaleffects
```

And if it's not found it you can still look for package name on  debian based distros :

```
apt-file search 'qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir'
libqt5qml-graphicaleffects: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/qmldir
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Qt5.8.0 and QtCreator 4.2.1 the import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0 was underlined because the module not found!

I added in the .pro file my path to the QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
**QML_IMPORT_PATH += /opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects**

After that it started working!

You can also add this to the "**Build Environment**" at the project page if the previous setting does not solve your problem. And restart QtCreator.

Comment: For dgj32784 the correct .pro file is the project file with I am currently working on!